# How to find whether the content copying of pdf file is allowed or not?

Tags: pdf, command-line, copying

How to find whether `content copying` of a pdf file is enabled or not in command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the community release of [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

```
cpdf -info file.pdf
```

And look at the contents of the "Permissions" line.